# Solve this differential equation $\Biggr(\frac{dy}{dx} -1\Bigg)\Bigg(y-x\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigg)=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve this differential equation:
>   $$\Biggr(\frac{dy}{dx} -1\Bigg)\Bigg(y-x\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigg)=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Biggr(\frac{dy}{dx} -1\Bigg)\Bigg(y-x\frac{dy}{dx}\Bigg)=\frac{dy}{dx}\implies(p-1)(y-xp)=p$, where $p\equiv \frac{dy}{dx}$

$\implies y-xp=\frac{p}{p-1}=\implies y=xp+\frac{p}{p-1}$ . . . . $(1)$

which is known as Clairaut’s equation.

So the general solution of the differential equation $(1)$ is

$y=cx+\frac{c}{c-1}$, where $c$ is the integrating constant.

---

If you once show that a differential equation is of Clairaut’s form i.e., of the form $$y=px+f(p)$$

Then for general solution of this kind of ODE, just replace $p\equiv \frac{dy}{dx}$ by the integrating constant $c$. i.e., its general solution is $$y=cx+f(c)$$

For more details about the solution of Clairaut’s equation, you may follow the reference:
"http://www.library.gscgandhinagar.in/assets/admin/images/MAT-102(UNIT1,2).pdf"

Comment: I think  if $y=x+1\pm2\sqrt{x}$ is a solution of the given differential equation then it must be the singular solution. A solution of a differential equation in which the number of arbitrary constants is equal to the order of the differential equation is called the general solution or complete integral or complete primitive.  A solution which can not be obtained from a general solution is called singular solution (See the reference I provide here).

Comment: OK. That's a matter of vocabulary. So, according to the provided definitions I agree with your answer. The singular solution $y=x+1\pm2\sqrt{x}$ is the envelope of the set of straight lines $y=cx+\frac{c}{c-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have $y(x)=px+\frac{p}{-1+p}$. Where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$ This is the Clairaut's equation . The solution will he of the form $y=cx+f(c)$ .Differentiating we have $dy=pdx+xdp+\frac{dp}{(1-p)^2}$ we can write $dy=pdx$ the equation becomes $-xdp=\frac{dp}{(1-p)^2}$ assuming $dp\neq 0$ we have $x=\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}$ put this value in the first equation and get an expression for $y(p)$. The $x(p),y(p) $ are called singular solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't be x=1/(1-p)^2  ?

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks for pointing g it out.

Answer (score 2):

Since nmasanta already posted the answer I don't edit my calculus.

I only add the singular solution $y=x+1\pm 2\sqrt{x}$ and a graph of the complete solutions of the ODE :

[image]

Comment: One should also not forget the composite solutions. One could, for example, come from the left along the $c=-0.2$ line, move some time along the singular solution and then leave to the right along the $c=0.5$ line.

Comment: Of course. You are right they are an infinity of composite solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $(y-x)'\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)'=\dfrac{y'}{y^2}$ and with substitutions $u=y-x$ and $\dfrac{x}{y}=v$ then
$$\dfrac{dv}{1-v}=\dfrac{du}{u^2-u}$$

Comment: $(y-x)'\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)'=u'v'=\frac{y'}{y^2}$ is correct. But you cannot integrate $u'v'$ as you did. $$\dfrac{du}{u}=\dfrac{dv}{v(v-1)}\quad\text{is false}$$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree. I think that $$\dfrac{dv}{1-v}=\dfrac{du}{u^2-u}\quad\text{is still false}$$ You should edit the steps of your calculus from $u'v'=\frac{y'}{y^2}$ to the proposed $\dfrac{dv}{1-v}=\dfrac{du}{u^2-u}$.

Comment: You should get $y=\frac{u}{1-v}$ and thus $u'v'=-(\frac1y)'=\frac{uv'-u'(v-1)}{u^2}$. Now explain how the variables get separated?